# Upgrading libc to the latest available version

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg

I am trying to update libc6 to 2.30 (latest version) on Ubuntu.

The latest package that I could find using apt was libc6(2.27)

I downloaded the binary from https://packages.debian.org/sid/libc6

When I issues `sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.30-7_amd64.deb`

```
installing libc6:amd64 would break locales, and
deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
```

I tried removing libc6 using `sudo apt remove libc6`

Though I stopped right there because I received an alert. Is there a way to update libc to 2.30 without creating issues with apt?

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this? even if possible, it would possibly create issues far beyond `apt` I think

Comment: there is a second package that relies on libc6 >= 2.29

Comment: I wish I had listened! System crashed! I may need to put the old libc back in place

Comment: Yeah installing packages from the _Debian_ repos on _Ubuntu_ is never a good idea :). The repos for each distro contain the packages that have been compiled and tested to work well with other packages from the same repo, not different ones.

Comment: Got it! I may be able to rescue the system by a live USB. I'll try!